# Upgrading a VS2010 project results in '0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have upgraded a VS2010 project by opening it in VS2012.

When starting debugging it was complaining that MSVCP100D.DLL cannot be found, by installing VS2010 Express the error is gone but the error mentioned in the question title is now shown.

Do you have an idea on what could be causing this ?

**EDIT**

The building process outputs : 
*1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library*

I have defined that option, now the project does not displays that error but still fails to run. The error happens in :

```
std::_Tree<_Traits> operator=(const _Myt & _Right)
```

Which is defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtree".

I've also tried to set the /VERBOSE:LIB switch and the following is printed (truncated for brevity):

```
Searching libraries
Searching \..\deps\lib\Win32\yaml-cppd.lib:
Searching \..\deps\lib\Win32\SDL_image.lib:
Searching \..\deps\lib\Win32\SDL_mixer.lib:
Searching \..\deps\lib\Win32\SDL_gfx.lib:
Searching \..\deps\lib\Win32\SDLmain.lib:
Searching \..\deps\lib\Win32\SDL.lib:
```

**Does that mean that I should get versions of these libraries built again VS2012 ?**

Additional information about the source project :

http://ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Compiling_with_Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_(OpenXcom)

Comment: Which program is crashing, your exe or VS?

Comment: Try deleting the debug folder and rebuilding the project from scratch. I had a similar issue the first time I ran my program after upgrading and that fixed it.

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd is a magic value, it means that you are using memory you've allocated with malloc or operator new and it is not initialized yet.  Could be a bug in your code.  But is *very* unhealthy to see that you've got a dependency on msvcp100d.dll.  That means you've got *two* copies of the CRT in your program, that doesn't often turn out well.  You've got a library or DLL that isn't rebuilt yet.

Comment: @CareyGregory It is the application.

Comment: @Caesar I have tried that but without success.

Comment: @HansPassant : Alright I'll try to get updated dependencies I've listed in my edit and see what it does, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure all(!) libraries are compiled with the same compiler and with compatible(!) switches (Eg: not mixing debug and release)